# Selenium Python - screenshot is scroll the page and the screenshot is also taken at position (0, 0), not the position we need

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, pycharm

I have the below code which takes screenshot of the page, but each time i call this method it starts to scroll the entire page and while taking screenshot it takes at position (0, 0) (at is at the top of the page)

```
ss = Screenshot.Screenshot()
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of(element))
ss.full_screenshot(driver, save_path=location, image_name=name)
```

is there anyway to stop the auto scroll and to take screens of the element which is needed.

Comment: For some drivers I think you can just do element.screenshot_as_png  Don't think you'd need to scroll.

Comment: @pcalkins, i even tried that, it takes screenshot but it is a rectangle color nothing of the page , there was no proper screenshot